# Are there any restrictions on implementing parts of the ISO C++ standard (or its proposals)?

Tags: c++, licensing

I have written an implementation of the ISO C++ proposal for `array_view`, which may make it into a future revision of the standard (C++17?). The implementation is all my own work, but by design reflects the proposal very closely and, for example, includes almost a direct copy of the class interfaces, all of which is not my own work. It's available on open-std.org as [N4512](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4512.html).

Before I post my implementation to GitHub - just the acknowledgement I am using someone else's work makes me want to check. Clearly both commercial and open source implementations are available, but they may know things I don't.  Am I free to post my implementation to GitHub, under my own (permissive) license?

Comment: Interesting question, but I think there once was a meta post saying legal advice is OT. Maybe I'm wrong though.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a specific programming question. You might want to check out http://law.stackexchange.com/